# Secondary Sort in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2, hadoop-partitioning

I am working on a `hadoop` project and after many visit to various blogs and reading the documentation, I realized I need to use secondary sort feature provided by `hadoop` framework.

My input format is of the form:

```
DESC(String) Price(Integer) and some other Text
```

I want the values in the reducer to be descending order of the Price.
Also while comparing `DESC` I have a method which takes two strings and a Percentage and if similarity between the two strings equals or is greater than the percentage then I should consider them as equal.

The problem is after the Reduce Job is finished I can see some `DESC` which is similar to the other string and yet they are in different group.

Here is my `compareTo` method of Composite key:

```
public int compareTo(VendorKey o) {
    int result =-
    result = compare(token, o.token, ":") >= percentage ? 0:1;
    if (result == 0) {
        return pid> o.pid  ?-1: pid < o.pid ?1:0;
    }
    return result;
}
```

and compare method of Grouping Comparator:

```
public int compare(WritableComparable a, WritableComparable b) {
    VendorKey one = (VendorKey) a;
    VendorKey two = (VendorKey) b;
    int result = ClusterUtil.compare(one.getToken(), two.getToken(), ":") >= one.getPercentage() ? 0 : 1;
    // if (result != 0)
    // return two.getToken().compareTo(one.getToken());
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Did fixing the compareTo method work for you?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `compareTo` method violates the common [contract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-) that requires `sgn(x.compareTo(y))`to be equal to `-sgn(y.compareTo(x))`.

Answer (score 0):

After your customWritable, give one basic partitioner with a composite key and NullWritable value. For example:

```
public class SecondarySortBasicPartitioner extends
    Partitioner<CompositeKeyWritable, NullWritable> {

    public int getPartition(CompositeKeyWritable key, NullWritable value,
            int numReduceTasks) {

        return (key.DEPT().hashCode() % numReduceTasks);
    }
}
```

And after this specify Key sort comparator and with 2 compositeKeyWritable variables the grouping will be done.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 procedures during shuffle: **Partitioning**, **Sorting** and **grouping**.
I guess that you have multiple reducers and your similar results were processed by different reducers for they are in different partitions.

You can set the number of reducers to 1 or set a custom Partitioner which extends **org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Partitioner** for you job.